# Automate Linux terminal commands with querys

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I want to automate some Linux terminal commands listed in that image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHD1z.png
I'm running a python script down below which is testing if the network is working and if not running a shell script (2nd code area) with the commands from the image. The problem is that I can't answer the question "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" with subprocess.Popen subprocess.call, os.system or with the shell script. Is there a way to do so? Thx for help ;)

python script:

```
import os
import subprocess
import requests
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)

x = True

print("starting...")
while x == True:
    def connected_to_internet(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=5):
        try:
            _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
            print("Internet connection available.\n")
            GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
            return True
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            print("No internet connection available.\n")
            GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
        return False

    if connected_to_internet() == True:
        subprocess.call('echo "Internet is working :)\n\n"', shell=True)
    else:
       subprocess.call('sh /home/pi/Desktop/start.sh', shell=True)

    time.sleep(5)
```

ssh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh "mynumber"-number@139.18.143.253
yes
"mypassword"
exit 0
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out how to answer the "*Are you sure you want to continue connecting?*" question, figure out instead how to prevent SSH from asking that in the first place. See this related post over at AskUbuntu: [ssh: automatically accept keys](https://askubuntu.com/q/123072/727997). This goes with all the prompts, find a way to configure connecting via SSH without prompts.